# Add a blank row after each unique value of a column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering if it might be possible to add one blank row after each unique value of `study` in my `data` below?

My `Desired_output` is below.

***Please note that this is a toy data. A functional answer is highly appreciated.***

```
data <- data.frame(study=c(rep(1,2),2:3), year=c(rep(2001,2),2002:2003))

Desired_output =
" study year
1     1 2001
2     1 2001
             # <- Blank row
3     2 2002
             # <- Blank row
4     3 2003"
```

Comment: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007509/how-to-insert-blank-row-in-specific-position-with-dplyr-in-r>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group_split` to split your data by group into a list of data frames. Then map a function over each list element and stack their output back into a data frame using `map_dfr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  group_split(study) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, .after = Inf))
```

**Output**

```
  study  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2001
2     1  2001
3    NA    NA
4     2  2002
5    NA    NA
6     3  2003
7    NA    NA
```

Comment: Super interesting! Just curious, if instead of one NA row, we wanted to add two NA rows, what should have changed?

Comment: Then I would replace the last line with `map_dfr(~ .x[1:(nrow(.x) + 2),])`. Then you also wouldn't need to load the `tibble` package.

Comment: Much appreciated. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
data_new <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(do.call(rbind, by(data_new, data$study, rbind, "")), -1)
```

```
    study year
1.1     1 2001
1.2     1 2001
1.3           
2.3     2 2002
2.2           
3.4     3 2003
```

Comment: `head(do.call(rbind, by(data, data$study, rbind, "")), -1)` seems sufficient without the first line.

Comment: Thank you for this advice!

Answer (score 1):

Group by a new column equal to study and then add a row to the end of each group using group_modify.  Finally remove study2 and the last row.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
 group_by(study2 = study) %>%
 group_modify(~ add_row(.)) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 select(-study2) %>%
 slice(-n())
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  study  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2001
2     1  2001
3    NA    NA
4     2  2002
5    NA    NA
6     3  2003
```

### Added

With dplyr 1.1.0, recently released, this can be shortened slightly:

```
data %>%
  mutate(study2 = study) %>%
  reframe(add_row(across()), .by = study2) %>%
  select(-study2) %>%
  slice(-n())
```